# Resetting Autoincrement in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this method which will remove all rows from a table but I also want it to reset the autoincrement so that when a new row is added it will start again. The SQL statement I'm using isn't working due to certain columns not existing. Am I doing it right?

```
private void rmvAll() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = appts.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = " + TABLE_NAME);

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you'll need single quotes around your table name, i.e.

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on dldnh's answer:

The following query will set `seq` to the largest value in the `col` identity column in the `Tbl` table, so there is no risk of violating constraints.

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = (SELECT MAX(col) FROM Tbl) WHERE name="Tbl"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying too hard.

Finally, I got this answer code...

```
Book.deleteAll(Book.class);
book=new Book(user, pass);
book.setId(Long.valueOf(book.listAll(Book.class).size()));
book.save();
```

this code work like delete and recreating the table.and reset id.

good luck

Comment: important :in work sugar orm in android studio must disable instant run

Answer (score 0):

you can also use delete() method of SQLiteDatabase, like this

```
db.delete("SQLITE_SEQUENCE","NAME = ?",new String[]{TABLE_NAME});
```