# How can I reset autoincrement using SqLite in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have to reset the autoincrement in my database. I can't do the "drop table" and recreate the 
table.

is there anyway to reset the autoincrement?

Comment: Maybe explain why you believe resetting auto increment in your scenario is required.  This breaks database integrity, I would think, so there is probably an alternative solution you should consider.

Comment: Is this the one you are searching for ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586269/how-can-i-reset-a-autoincrement-sequence-number-in-sqlite

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting Autoincrement in Android SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759502/resetting-autoincrement-in-android-sqlite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using this Query

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + name_of_the_table + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, maybe it will help

```
    public boolean deleteAll() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.delete("SQLITE_SEQUENCE","NAME=?",new String[]{TABLE_NAME});
    int affectedRows = db.delete(this.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    return affectedRows > 1;
    }
```