# Clear table and reset autoincrement primary key

Tags: java, android, android-room

I want to delete all from my table and reset autoincrement primary key. I do this :

```
@Query("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='bin';")
void delete();


@Query("DELETE FROM bin")
void nukeTable();

@Query("UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1 WHERE name = 'bin';")
void resetPrimaryKey();
```

But it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resetting Autoincrement in Android SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759502/resetting-autoincrement-in-android-sqlite)

Comment: @majidghafouri it does not work

Comment: you cannot `"reset autoincrement primary key"` - btw why would you want to do that at all?

Comment: @pskink why ? what happend when my table have been a max value from auto incremet ?

Comment: you mean after 2^64 inserts? if your app for example makes one million inserts per second so it would happen after 584942 years

Comment: @pskink I only ask what happend and why in room i can not reset primary key

Comment: read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: @pskink ok , and I have one more question in any possibility to retrieving a livedata HashMap ? in my table I have a one columnt which I want to have like a primary key

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200327/discussion-between-kpokrywja-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that ROOM protects against the use of SQLite tables i.e. those that start with sqlite_, as such you cannot directly reset sqlite_sequence within ROOM.

Below are two ways of circumventing this and to realise the goal of resetting the sequence, within ROOM. A third option, not shown, would be to close the ROOM database and then access the database using an SQLiteDatabase instance to reset the sequence.

## Option A

You can do this by **DROP**ing the table and then recreating it using a SupportSQLiteDatabase instance.

The following is a demo of option A (but also includes unnecessary closing of the Room database and also use of the database outside of room object-wise, however this has been added as proof of the technique by extracting data from sqlite_sequence).

## NOTE

The above code is just a demonstration of the technique and there are issues with the above code swapping between room and non-room, which isn't required for the solution.

The core testing code :-

```
    //Stage 1 load some data
    getRoomDB();
    mRowIdTestDao = mRTDB.rowIdTestDao();
    mRowIdTestDao.insertManyRowIdTests(
            new RowIdTest("A"),
            new RowIdTest("B"),
            new RowIdTest("C")
    );

    // Stage 2 close to room and dump sqlite_sequence
    //mRTDB.close();
    getNonRoomDB();
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mNotRoomdb.query("sqlite_sequence",null,null,null,null,null,null));
    mNotRoomdb.close();

    //Stage 3 clear sqlite_sequence by dropping the table using SupportSQLiteDatabase
    getRoomDB();
    mSuppDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE RowIdTest"); //<<<<<<<<<< DROP THE TABLE
    mSuppDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RowIdTest (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT)"); //<<<<<<<<<< CREATE THE TABLE

    // Stage 4 close to room and dump sqlite_sequence
    mRTDB.close();
    getNonRoomDB();
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mNotRoomdb.query("sqlite_sequence",null,null,null,null,null,null));
    mNotRoomdb.close();

    // Stage 5 check that all is OK again (add some rows)
    getRoomDB();
    mRowIdTestDao.insertManyRowIdTests(
            new RowIdTest("A"),
            new RowIdTest("B"),
            new RowIdTest("C")
    );

    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mSuppDB.query("SELECT * FROM RowIdTest"));
```

The called methods :-

```
RoomDatabase.Callback getSuppDb = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        mSuppDB = db;
    }
};

private void getRoomDB() {
    mRTDB = Room.databaseBuilder(this,RoomTestingDatabase.class,"rtdb.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .addCallback(getSuppDb)
            .build();
}

private void getNonRoomDB() {
    mNotRoomdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
            this.getDatabasePath("rtdb.db").getPath(),
            null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE
    );
}
```

## Result from Log

```
2019-10-03 17:13:25.506 W/SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal mode of '/data/user/0/art.roomtesting/databases/rtdb.db' from 'wal' to 'TRUNCATE' because the database is locked.  This usually means that there are other open connections to the database which prevents the database from enabling or disabling write-ahead logging mode.  Proceeding without changing the journal mode.
2019-10-03 17:13:25.508 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@add2875
2019-10-03 17:13:25.508 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-10-03 17:13:25.508 I/System.out:    name=RowIdTest
2019-10-03 17:13:25.508 I/System.out:    seq=6
2019-10-03 17:13:25.508 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:13:25.509 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-10-03 17:13:25.511 E/SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE] database is locked
2019-10-03 17:13:25.511 W/SQLiteConnection: Could not change the database journal mode of '/data/user/0/art.roomtesting/databases/rtdb.db' from 'wal' to 'TRUNCATE' because the database is locked.  This usually means that there are other open connections to the database which prevents the database from enabling or disabling write-ahead logging mode.  Proceeding without changing the journal mode.
2019-10-03 17:13:25.512 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@38ae98
2019-10-03 17:13:25.513 I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@f873957
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out:    id=1
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out:    name=A
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out:    id=2
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out:    name=B
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-10-03 17:13:25.518 I/System.out:    id=3
2019-10-03 17:13:25.519 I/System.out:    name=C
2019-10-03 17:13:25.519 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:13:25.519 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

## Option B

The other alternative is to create table with AUTOINCREMENT and thus the rowid is generated based solely upon the rows in the table. I believe that there is some confusion in regards to not using AUTOINCREMENT the (or a) way is to **NOT code autoGenerate = true** AND use **Long** not **long** (or Integer not int for the type, not advised).

Consider the RowTestId table/entity used above, it is :-

```
@Entity
public class RowIdTest {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String name;


    public RowIdTest() {};

    @Ignore
    public RowIdTest(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The equivalent non AUTOINCREMENT version would be :-

```
@Entity
public class AltRowIdTest {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id; //<<<<<<<<<< Long not long
    private String name;


    public AltRowIdTest() {};

    @Ignore
    public AltRowIdTest(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() { //<<<<<<<<<< Long not long
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) { //<<<<<<<<<< Long not long
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Also consider :-

```
    @Query("DELETE FROM AltRowIdTest")
    int clearAllAltRowIdTestRows();
```

And then the following code :-

```
    //Option B
    mAltRowIdTestDao.insertManyRowIdTests(new AltRowIdTest("X"),new AltRowIdTest("Y"),new AltRowIdTest("Z"));
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mSuppDB.query("SELECT * FROM AltRowIdTest"));
    mAltRowIdTestDao.clearAllAltRowIdTestRows();
    mAltRowIdTestDao.insertManyRowIdTests(new AltRowIdTest("X"),new AltRowIdTest("Y"),new AltRowIdTest("Z"));
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mSuppDB.query("SELECT * FROM AltRowIdTest"));
```

The result in the log being :-

```
2019-10-03 17:49:31.783 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@561c44
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out:    id=1
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out:    name=A
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out:    id=2
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out:    name=B
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out:    id=3
2019-10-03 17:49:31.785 I/System.out:    name=C
2019-10-03 17:49:31.786 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:49:31.786 I/System.out: <<<<<


2019-10-03 17:49:31.793 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@f369662
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out:    id=1
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out:    name=X
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out:    id=2
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out:    name=Y
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out: 2 {
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out:    id=3
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out:    name=Z
2019-10-03 17:49:31.794 I/System.out: }
2019-10-03 17:49:31.795 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

i.e. The id column restarts from 1 after deleting all rows, or different to Option A, if rows at the end are deleted it will re-use the freed id's (bot not if the end row is not deleted). Furthermore unlike with AUTOINCREMENT if the highest id value (9223372036854775807) is reached *(reason id should always be long or Long, not int or Integer)* an SQLITE_FULL exception may not result as SQLite will attempt to use a random unused number *(you can also nearly double the available range by using negative values)*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it with two queries:

```
delete from your_table;
```

and

```
UPDATE SQLIT_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name='bin'
```

This will do the trick. ID will restart.

Comment: when I do this I only clear my table but not reset primary key

Comment: try edited answer, set 0 and check it again @kpokrywja

Comment: Where I have to place this command. In DAO interface the command (UPDATE SQLIT_SEQUENCE SET seq = 0 WHERE name='bin')  isn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple workaround by:

1. delete current db
2. recreate AppDb instance
3. restart activity

In your AppDB

```
public static Completable clearMyTables(Context context) {
        context.deleteDatabase("MyDatabase");
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> INSTANCE = Room
                .databaseBuilder(context, AppDB.class, "MyDatabase")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build());
    }
```

On `Completable` complete response:

```
@Override
public void onComplete() {
    finishAffinity();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
}
```