# SQLite Java: update table ID's after deleting item automatically

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm using SQLite to store data and if i delete the last row, ID is 4 and after that add a new row and the ID is 5 and it should be 4. And when trying to view the data it crashes since it can't find data from ID 5.

[Database Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51F2N.png)

In database inspector left of the ID column is a row number. is this accessible since that would solve the problem or is it just a row number indicator in Android studio.

Thank you and have  a nice day!

Comment: Alright looks like the row number is not accessible.

Comment: Deleting the last row does not make that row ID available for the next new row.

Comment: I need to get the ID because in adapterview i put i value as an EXTRA and based on that i find the information from database.

Comment: In the SQLite schema there is a table `sqlite_sequence` in which the counters for the automatic sequences are stored. You can reset them, but then they start again from zero and you will run into new problems.
Interesting why there is an error if your last ID = 5. you should change your query or add your own ID to your table.

Comment: If you are relying on the ID's to be consecutive then you are doing something wrong. If you post your code I may be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @JimRhodes Now if i delete the last one and add new one it does give the right id because of `String strSQL1 = "UPDATE people_table SET id = (id +1) WHERE id < 1"; ` `db.execSQL(strSQL1);` but if i delete something from between the first and last one the id goes wrong.

Comment: Never mind i got it working adding a new update beneath that  `String strSQL = "UPDATE people_table SET id = (id -1) WHERE id > 1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by adding these:

```
String strSQL1 = "UPDATE people_table SET id = (id +1) WHERE id < 1";
String strSQL = "UPDATE people_table SET id = (id -1) WHERE id > 1";
db.execSQL(strSQL);
db.execSQL(strSQL1);
```

The `id` goes right one even if I delete something between first and last one.
And you need to remove `autoincrement` from `id` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a method to recover the last item that you insert, or the one with the higher id, with that you have the value of the next id that you need to put as an extra. If you need it when there are no values then save it when you delete the last item, or reset the data base so that ir reestart the count of the id

Comment: Do you know that is it possible to reset the sqlite_sequence? I can't seem to find a way or where it's located. Some people were sharing that but couldn't really find a way to reset it by executing sql `UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq=0 WHERE name = " + TABLE_NAME`

Comment: i saw that methot too but the problem seems to be with room , found another post that have some answers that i think will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212703/clear-table-and-reset-autoincrement-primary-key